Datadog metric query for count of grouped tag values
What I am looking for
How does one query count of a metric on Datadog grouped by tag values?
Let's say the metric orders has tags category and status and we need to get the count of failed orders grouped by the category tag and display it in a table / top list dashboard widget as follows:



category
failures




apparel
20


gadgets
24



What I have tried
The query that I have tried just sums all the failed orders up (for all categories):
sum:orders{status:failed}.as_count()


On going through the Datadog aggregation methods and space aggregation documents, it can be seen that they support group by aggregation in the queries for metrics.
In this case aggregation can be achieved with sum by in the following way:
sum:orders{status:failed} by{category}.as_count()

One can refer the Datadog nested queries multilayer space aggregation for more examples.
